# Uri containing \\ as parmater

Tags: c#, uri

I have the following Uri pattern

```
var uri = string.Format("/order/{0}/parmaters", userName);
```

and 
userName  can contain domain  i.e `myDomain\\userName`

Is there a way to pass userName  to the Uri ?

Comment: have you tried using `%5C`?

Comment: You need to URL encode your parameters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[URL-encode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.urlencode.aspx) any value being used in a URL:

```
string.Format("/order/{0}/parmaters", HttpUtility.UrlEncode(userName))
```

This will replace any characters with their URL-friendly equivalents.  So this:

```
/order/myDomain\\userName/parmaters
```

becomes this:

```
/order/myDomain%5C%5CuserName/parmaters
```

which would very likely be URL-decoded by pretty much any web framework handling the request whenever it comes time to extract that value.  But, if not, URL-decoding in code is just as easy.